# Make div orbit around a moving div

Tags: html, css, css-animations

I'm trying to learn `animation` and `keyframes` in CSS3, and I wonder how I can make `#moon-orbit` orbit around `#earth`? Like it does in real life, you know.

```
html, body {
    background-color : #000000;
    height : 90%;
    width : 90%;
}

#sun {
    background-color : #ba8f27;
    border-radius : 200px;
    box-shadow : 0 0 128px red;
    margin-top : -100px; 
    margin-left : -100px;
    left : 50%;
    height : 200px;
    position : absolute;
    top : 50%;
    width : 200px;
}

#earth-orbit {
    border: 2px solid #373737;
    border-radius: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    height: 500px;
    margin-top: -250px;
    margin-left: -250px;
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    width: 500px;

    -webkit-animation: spin-right 10s linear infinite;
    -moz-animation: spin-right 10s linear infinite;
    -ms-animation: spin-right 10s linear infinite;
    -o-animation: spin-right 10s linear infinite;
    animation: spin-right 10s linear infinite;
}

#moon-orbit {
    border-radius: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    height: 500px;
    margin-top: -250px;
    margin-left: -250px;
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    width: 500px;

    transform: rotate(360deg);
    transform-origin: 50% 100%;
}

#earth {
    background-color : #2d7ddc;
    border-radius : 50px;
    margin-left : -25px;
    margin-top : -25px;
    height : 50px;
    left : 50%;
    position : absolute;
    top : 0%;
    width : 50px;
}

#moon {
    background-color : #b2b2b2;
    border-radius : 50px;
    margin-left : -25px;
    margin-top : -25px;
    height : 16px;
    left : 43%;
    position : absolute;
    top : 0%;
    width : 16px;
}



@-webkit-keyframes spin-right {
    100% {
        -webkit-transform: rotate(360deg);
    }
}



<div id="sun"></div>

<div id="earth-orbit">
    <div id="earth"></div>

    <div id="moon-orbit">
        <div id="moon"></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

[jsFiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/edgren/rm3u0y09/)

Comment: Please tell specifically what your problem is. As it stands, this question is likely to be closed since there isn't actually any clear problem or question here.

Comment: The question is very clear: how I can make `#moon-orbit` orbit around `#earth`? The problem is that I don't know how I can accomplish this. I have Googled but no solution was found, more than how a div can rotate around another div. Not how a div can orbit around a div, that are already orbiting around another div

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can add a holder for the moon and positioned it in the center of the earth and rotate that div:

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/rm3u0y09/2/)

Added stuff:

HTML:

```
<div class="moon-holder">
    <div id="moon"></div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.moon-holder {
    position: absolute;
    left: 50%;
    top: 0;
    width: 50px;
    height: 50px;
    margin: -25px 0 0 -25px;
    -webkit-animation: spin-right 5s linear infinite;
    -moz-animation: spin-right 5s linear infinite;
    -ms-animation: spin-right 5s linear infinite;
    -o-animation: spin-right 5s linear infinite;
    animation: spin-right 5s linear infinite;
}
```

Comment: *Descend, bold traveller, into the crater of the jökull of Snæfell...* ;) - Sorry, I couldn't resist